# Pass One Extra parameter to MVC controller Index method on Form RePost

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC controller which accepts two parameters.

```
public class RiskController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int SquadId, string RiskItems = "Open")
    {
        // Do Stuff here, Populate Model, and then...
        ViewBag.SquadID = SquadId;
        Return View(Model);
    }
}
```

In my View I have a form with a Drop down list.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Risk", FormMethod.Get))
{
     @Html.DropDownList("RiskItems", new List<SelectListItem>
      {
              new SelectListItem() {Text = "Open Risks only", Value="Open"},
              new SelectListItem() {Text = "Closed Risks only", Value="Closed"},
              new SelectListItem() {Text = "All Risks", Value="All"}
      }, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:auto" })

    <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>       
}
```

My Goal is to Reload the View when I choose a value from teh drop down and Hit the submit button.

With my current code, I am able to post the form, and the drop down value is successfully posted in my controller inside the `RiskItems` parameter. but How do I also pass the `SquadID` parameter from the form?

I have already captured the value of the  `SquadID` parameter inside a `ViewBag`. Can I use it to Resend the value in the Index Method of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to change the Form method to Post from Get and used this.`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Risk", new { SquadId = @ViewBag.SquadID }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`
```